# Getting methods from reflection and assigning them to delegate

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I want to get all methods from class through reflection and assign them to created delegate or instantiate a new delegate with them.

I am trying to learn reflection and delegates and I want to use reflection here because I don't like the way it looks like with `+=`

I tried to assign with Delegate.CreateDelegate method but there isn't any overloads that gets an array of MethodInfo which I get from reflection.

```
//public delegate void GetIntegersPower(int x);
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //old way
        //GetIntegersPower iP = Power.Square;
        //iP += Power.Cubed;
        //iP += Power.xToThePowerOfFour;
        //iP += Power.xToThePowerOfFive;
        //iP += Power.xToThePowerOfSix;
        //iP(3);

        //new way
        var powerMembers = typeof(Power).GetMethods();
        var del=(Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>), powerMembers); //error
        del(3);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Power
{
    public static void Square(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of two equals {x * x}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void Cubed(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of three equals {Math.Pow(x,3)}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void xToThePowerOfFour(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of four equals {Math.Pow(x,4)}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void xToThePowerOfFive(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of five equals {Math.Pow(x,5)}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void xToThePowerOfSix(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of six equals {Math.Pow(x,6)}" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Now I am able only to execute one method when I supply to MethodInfo index but I want to create multicast delegate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first step to take here is to read the text of the error message and see what it's telling you. The second step is to share that information with us, as text, in your question.

Comment: you have to chain in the delegate using `+=` instead of `=`

Comment: What do you want to happen when you call `del(3)`? It executes _all_ the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Working version using Multi-cast delegate:**

```
// In this solution we don't need to define Multi Cast Delegate explicitly
// It is automatically initialized and chained
class Program
{
    // Main Function 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // Fetch the MethodInfo array using reflection API
        var powerMembers = typeof(Power).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        // Initialize Delegate using first Index
        var del=(Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>),typeof(Power), powerMembers[0].Name);

        // Add other methods beside first method
        for(int index = 1; index < powerMembers.Length; index++)
        {
            del += (Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>),typeof(Power), powerMembers[index].Name); 
        }

        // Execute All
        del(3);

    }
}
// Made class static, it can also be an instance class and method and you need to apply the BindingFlags in reflection correctly
static class Power
{
    public static void Square(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of two equals {x * x}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void Cubed(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of three equals {Math.Pow(x, 3)}" + Environment.NewLine); 
    public static void xToThePowerOfFour(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of four equals {Math.Pow(x, 4)}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void xToThePowerOfFive(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of five equals {Math.Pow(x, 5)}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void xToThePowerOfSix(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of six equals {Math.Pow(x, 6)}" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

> **Result**

```
The number of 3 to the power of two equals 9

The number of 3 to the power of three equals 27

The number of 3 to the power of four equals 81

The number of 3 to the power of five equals 243

The number of 3 to the power of six equals 729
```

Using static methods here is a convenience, you have to supply the object instance is the class is non static and need to use correct filtering in the Reflection API

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad the solution helped

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to limit your reflection to `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static` - otherwise you'll pick up `ToString` which doesn't match the signature you're after.

You can use your pre-defined delegate.

```
public delegate void GetIntegersPower(int x);
public static void Main()
{
    var powerMembers = typeof(Power).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    GetIntegersPower del  = null;
    foreach(var powerMember in powerMembers)
    {
        del+=(GetIntegersPower)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(GetIntegersPower), powerMember);             
    }

    del(3);
}
public class Power
{
    public static void Square(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of two equals {x * x}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void Cubed(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of three equals {Math.Pow(x,3)}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void xToThePowerOfFour(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of four equals {Math.Pow(x,4)}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void xToThePowerOfFive(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of five equals {Math.Pow(x,5)}" + Environment.NewLine);
    public static void xToThePowerOfSix(int x) => Console.WriteLine($"The number of {x} to the power of six equals {Math.Pow(x,6)}" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/44xilG

Comment: Really neat! Thank you Sir!